# Custom class designer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer

I made an application at the office which runs a bunch of ProcessManager objects which themselves run a bunch of Process objects.
I have been thinking in creating a wizard to create automaticly the classes needed, but I want now to create a custom designer for creating and editing the classes. By designer, I mean like  the LinqToSql designer and so on.
I wasn't able to find any information about it, or at least clear one. I've been looking at how to create a new editor for vs 2010 or add design-time ability, but none of theses researches helped me.
The ideal would be to have let's say ProcessManagerClass1.cs and ProcessManagerClass1.designer.cs and when opening the first one, it would open the custom designer.
Do you know how to do it and give me some links for tutorials or documentation??

Thank you for your help,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the [Visualization and Modeling SDK for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23025), which was formerly known as the Domain Specific Languages SDK. It is the way to create custom designers in Visual Studio. To use it, you first have to install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK ([SP1 here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21835), but you may have to run them in order, which means [this first](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2680), then the [Visualization SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23025), then [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21835))